# Access credential callback value firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am trying to access the callback value of the firebase credential method but I am not succeeding

I tried this:

```
   $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
     .then(function(success) {
        console.log(success);
        var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(success.authResponse.accessToken);
        console.log(credential);
                        Auth.$signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
       })
      }, function (error) {
      console.log(error.errorMessage);
    });
```

[image]

But I only get the value of console.log (credential) and console.log (success).

I think it's a silly mistake, but I can not identify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation

```
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
```

not sure where `Auth` is coming from or `$signInWithCredential`

[Advanced: Handle the sign-in flow manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login)